# How to add icon property in button widget using class in flutter

Tags: flutter, button, icons

I created a class of **RoundedButton** and call that class where I want a button. I added all required properties for a button. here is my class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function press;
  final Color color, textColor;
  final Icons icon;
  const RoundedButton({
    Key key,
    this.text,
    this.press,
    this.color = Colors.grey,
    this.icon,
    this.textColor = Colors.white,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);  
   
        return Material(
          elevation: 5.0,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
          
          child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
            onPressed: press,
            child:Row(
              children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.icon)),
              Text(text,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: style.copyWith(
                  color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
        ),
          ],
        )
        // child: Text(text,
        //     textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            
        //     style: style.copyWith(
        //         color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
        // ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here it calls look like

```
RoundedButton(text: "Time out",color: Colors.white,),),
```

So, when i call this RoundedButton i can change the properties value as required for each button, I want to change icon of buttons too, so my problem is i am not accessing `icon` variable on `Icon(Icons.icon)`.

Kindly please help how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `final Icons icon` to the `final Icon icon`

and replace `Icon(Icons.icon)` with `icon`

to be like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function press;
  final Color color, textColor;
  final Icon icon;
  const RoundedButton({
    Key key,
    this.text,
    this.press,
    this.color = Colors.grey,
    this.icon = const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
    this.textColor = Colors.white,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);

    return Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
      child: MaterialButton(
          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          onPressed: press,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              icon,
              Text(text,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: style.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ],
          )
          // child: Text(text,
          //     textAlign: TextAlign.left,

          //     style: style.copyWith(
          //         color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
          // ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it print this error ,Row's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0 ,  when i call RoundedButton like this  RoundedButton(icon: Icon(Icons.timer_off),text: "Time out",color: Colors.white,)),

Comment: You can check if the Icon is null put an empty container like this

icon == null ? Container() : icon,

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Just added this statement `icon == null ? Container() : icon,` on Amin Al-jebbeh solution

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:attendance_system_app/new.dart';

class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function press;
  final Color color, textColor;
  final Icon icon;
  const RoundedButton({
    Key key,
    this.text,
    this.press,
    this.color = Colors.grey,
    this.icon,
    this.textColor = Colors.white,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);  
   
        return Material(
          elevation: 5.0,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
          
          child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
            onPressed: press,
            child:Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                 icon == null ? Container() : 
             icon,
              Text(text,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: style.copyWith(
                  color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
        ),
          ],
        )
        // child: Text(text,
        //     textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            
        //     style: style.copyWith(
        //         color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
        // ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```